# Count number of occurrences of each month in db table asp.net linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a table which contains a `date` col.

I want to use LINQ query and count the occurrence of each month and display it like `month, occurrence of month in the table`

`1=2(1 is month, 2 is number of occurrence),2=5,3=12` and so on using asp.net.

Can somebody please tell me how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u write any code yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
var dates = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i=>new DateTime(2015,i%3+1,1));
var grouped = dates.GroupBy(d => d.Month).Select(g => string.Format("{0}={1}", g.Key, g.Count()));
// Now grouped will have your desired data (list of occurrences)
```

I have used dummy dates here. You need to `Select` the date column from the database instead.

Comment: in above query where do i use my query to select from the table.

Comment: You need to populate `dates` instead of dummy dates. Example: `var dates = yourEntities.YourTable.Select(x=>x.YourDateColumn);`

Comment: lbl.Text = grouped.ToString();   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.String] out put

Comment: That is wrong. You need to do this instead: `lbl.Text = string.Join(",", grouped);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following if you want to use lambda instead of long linq. Although you need to convert numeric month to something texual.

```
var somedates = new List<DateTime>() { 
            DateTime.Now, 
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(10), 
            DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1), 
            DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).AddDays(5)};

var months = somedates.GroupBy(x => x.Month).Select(g => new {Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count()});
```

Comment: in above query where do i use my query to select from the table.

Comment: you should replace new List<DateTime>() wiht your list of dates or data

Comment: lbl.Text = months .ToString(); System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.String] out put